# Different transaction commits at same time

Tags: c#, oracle, ibm-mq

I have a WebSphere MQ and my Oracle database. I get messages from the MQ and write them into the database. This is done with this code at the moment:

```
private MQHandler _mqHandler;
private OracleDBConnector _db;
private OracleDBUtils _dbUtil;

_db = new OracleConnection();

_db.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
_db.Open();


try 
{
    using (TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope())
    {
        _db.BeginTransaction();

        //read from Queue
        oMqResult = _mqHandler.ReadTransactionQMsg(sChannelName);
        //write into database and some other magic 
        ........

        if (noError) {
            // Commit queue
            _mqHandler.Commit();
            // Commit database
            _db.Commit();
            // Commit transactionscope
            tran.Complete();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _mqHandler.Backout();
    _db.Rollback(); 
}
```

If no exception occur, everythings fine. But my problem is: what happens when `_mqHandler.Commit();` works fine and then the `_db.Commit();` fail? And how exactly is TransactionScope working in this example? Can this tran-Object commit and rollback the queue and database?

Comment: I think you should read something about XA (distributed transactions).

Answer (score 0):

If an exception is thrown before tran.Complete() is issued,then both the operations should rollback

Comment: Even after _mqHandler.Commit() / _db.Commit() ?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response. Looking at your code again, for an db operation to be under transaction scope you have to issue _db.Open(); within the transactionScope to make sure that db operation is under a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to study these terms as follows.

1. XA Transaction (Two Phase Commit (2PC))
2. JTA (Java Transaction API)
3. TransactionManager(configuring global coordination of transactions by implement class)